# Tex Editor from main-repository

Tags: 12.04, kile

I am looking for a TeX editor from a main repository. Since I am very causious on intalling stuff from universe I would like to avoid TeXmaker and Kile :(
Can anyone suggest a program?

Comment: Why the caution? These well-known programs are quite safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only Tex stuff that is Canonical supported is TeX Live...an as far as I can see there are no editors here...just libraries to allow working with stuff.  These libraries are the stable versions and not the latest version so are out of date.  Even TeX group recommend using their more up-to-date stuff.

However to answer your question no directly installable binaries...the closest you can get is to install TexLive, Install GnuEmacs, and then extend Emacs with [AUC Tex](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/)

For a native WYSIWIG editor however you need to go outside Canonical and explore the multiverse, and in addition to those two you have mentioned you can get [Winefish](http://viettug.github.io/winefish/) is simple to use, [LatexZilla](https://projects.gnome.org/latexila/) is associated with Gnome, [TexStudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) is derived from TextMaker, [TexWorks](http://www.tug.org/texworks/) is an editor that is included in some Mac and Windows versions of Tex Live, but not in their Linux packaging.